# Read (and convert) matrix on a file in C

Tags: c, file, matrix

I wrote this function in C:

```
void fill_matrix(double **m, int r, int c, char *file) {
    int i, j;
    FILE *temp_file = fopen(file, "r");
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            fscanf(temp_file, "%lf", &m[i][j]);
        }
    }
    fclose(temp_file);
}
```

Matrix is defined and allocated in this way:

```
double **m;
m = (double **)malloc(r * sizeof(double *));
for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
    m[i] = (double *)malloc(c * sizeof(double));
```

`r` and `c` are the numbers of rows and columns.

Params are:

```
fill_matrix(m, r, c, filename);
```

In the **testin.txt** file I have this matrix:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 1 2 3
```

But my output is:

```
1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 
5.00 6.00 0.00 0.00 
9.00 1.00 2.00 3.00
```

Can you please let me know how to solve this? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why are you reading it as doubles?

Comment: What is `m`? What are the values or `r` and `c`? How do you call this function? How do you print the values? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: m is te matrix, r is the number of rows and c is the number of columns.

I call this function in this way: `fill_matrix(matrix, rows, columns, argv[1]);`

To print the values: `fprintf(temp_file, "%lf ", m[i][j]);`

Comment: And how is this `matrix` *declared*? As an array of arrays of `double`? As a pointer to pointer to `double`? Again, *please* edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Edit question with called function and parameter passed

Comment: Do not overlook that your `fscanf` should have a space in it to account for whitespace, which will otherwise cause you headaches.

Comment: We still have no idea how you produced the output that you're complaining about or how `r` and `c` get their values.

Comment: You *must always* check the return value of `scanf` family functions. Without doing it first any other attempt at solving problem is a waste of time.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Not needed, the `"%f"` format specifier (with or without modifiers) will automatically skip leading whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `create_matrix` should return `m` instead of taking it as an argument.

As coded, the function `create_matrix` does the allocation but the pointer is a local variable and gets lost when the function returns.

You should also check the return values of `fscanf()` and `malloc()` to detect and handle failures properly.

You should also free the allocated objects after use.

Here is a corrected version of your code:

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "library.h"

int main(void) {
    int rows, columns;

    // Take the order matrix
    printf("Number of rows: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &rows) != 1)
        return 1;
    printf("Number of columns: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &columns) != 1)
        return 1;

    matrix = create_matrix(rows, columns);
    if (matrix != NULL) {
        if (!fill_matrix(matrix, rows, columns, "testin.txt")) {
            print_matrix(matrix, rows, columns, "testout.txt");
        }
        free_matrix(matrix, rows, cols);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**library.h**

```
double **create_matrix(int r, int c);
void free_matrix(double **m, int r, int c);
int fill_matrix(double **m, int r, int c, const char *file);
int print_matrix(double **m, int r, int c, const char *file);
```

**library.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "library.h"

double **create_matrix(int r, int c) {
    int i;
    double **m = malloc(r * sizeof(*m));
    if (m != NULL) {
        for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            m[i] = malloc(c * sizeof(*m[i]));
            if (m[i]) == NULL) {
                while (i-- > 0) {
                    free(m[i]);
                }
                free(m);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    return m;
}

void free_matrix(double **m, int r, int c) {
    int i;
    if (m) {
        for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            free(m[i]);
        }
        free(m);
    }
}

int fill_matrix(double **m, int r, int c, const char *file) {
    int i, j;
    FILE *temp_file = fopen(file, "r");

    if (temp_file == NULL)
        return -1;

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            if (fscanf(temp_file, "%lf", &m[i][j]) != 1) {
                fclose(temp_file);
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(temp_file);
    return 0;
}

int print_matrix(double **m, int r, int c, const char *file) {
    int i, j;
    FILE *temp_file = fopen(file, "w");

    if (temp_file == NULL)
        return -1;

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            fprintf(temp_file, "%f%c", m[i][j], " \n"[j == c - 1]);
        }
    }
    fclose(temp_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't really have to repost the full code, only the changes you made.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I made changes in every function posted. The main issue was the broken API in `create_matrix()` butthe rest of the code needed corrections too.

Comment: Then it would be a good idea to point out all the changes you made.